# Too many Gmail API push notifications when sending emails with many large attachments

Tags: email, push-notification, google-cloud-platform, gmail-api

I'm using the Gmail API (With the Google Cloud Platform) to send push notifications to my server. This mailbox is never actually accessed by a user, it only exists for the purpose of sending push notifications to a route on my server that retrieves the latest email from the mailbox.

Everyday, I have a cron job that renews the `Users: watch()` on this email address. It's only one email address associated with a single topic in the Cloud Console with one `push` subscription to my server. My controller then calls `Users.messages: list` to get a list of recent emails, followed by `Users.messages: get` to get the most recent email with all attachment IDs/filenames, and finally `Users.messages.attachments: get` to get each data for each attachment.

I've noticed that when I send emails with lots of attachment data (25 Mb of image data for instance), I start receiving a series of push notifications, each with the same `message_id` and timestamp in the data sent with the push notification POST request. For now, I'm dealing with this by saving the `message_id` in a cache for a little while to prevent my server from reacting to a single push notification more than once.

Although my solution works nicely, I'm curious if anyone else has experienced a problem like this, or whether this is a bug in the Gmail API or Cloud Platform. Any help or advice is appreciated!

Comment: I see similar behavior, too many notifications, for every possible action, email received, removed, opened, archived, the label added, label removed, ...

Comment: are anyone find solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a bug in Gmail or in Cloud Platform.

Actually, as discussed in [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#overview),  Gmail API have already implemented the use of [**Cloud Pub/Sub API**](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview) to deliver push notifications. This allows notification via a variety of methods including webhooks and polling on a single subscription endpoint. And, with this API, using a single topic for all Gmail API push notifications for all application is recommended.

Detailed information can be found in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#overview) and to get familiarized with this Cloud Pub/Sub API, I suggest that you go through [Google Cloud Pub/Sub Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/).

Comment: Do you think there is a way to only receive a push for an email received, and ignore all other events?